# Excel formula to allow me to retrieve the codes of the most valuables drinks

Tags: excel, excel-formula, group-by

Good night,

I'm trying to think of a simple excel formula to allow me to get the codes of the most valuables drinks.

I don't wanna use **PivotTable** for this one.

Ex:

[image]

I want to retrieve, for MALIBU, the code **8991**

For JAMESON, the code **6113** etc

I'm stuck here since I woke up haha

Thanks!

Comment: Use the `MAXIFS`  and/or `FILTER` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below formula for dynamic spill result-

```
=LET(x,UNIQUE(C2:C12),y,BYROW(x,LAMBDA(r,INDEX(SORT(FILTER(A2:B12,C2:C12=r),2,-1),1,1))),HSTACK(x,y))
```

[image]

Comment: 'Simple excel formula'... haha. Smart answer though.

Answer (score 1):

Using `MAX` function to **consider the scenario where more than one code for a given drink can have the maximum value**. In cell `E2` use the following formula:

```
=LET(rng, A2:C13, codes, INDEX(rng,,1), values, INDEX(rng,,2), 
  drinks, INDEX(rng,,3), drinksUx, UNIQUE(drinks), 
  maxValues, BYROW(drinksUx, LAMBDA(ux, 
    TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTER(codes, (drinks = ux) 
      * (values = MAX(FILTER(values, drinks=ux))))))),
  HSTACK(drinksUx, maxValues)
)
```

Here is the output:
[image: sample excel file]

**Note**: Another code for `HEINEKEN` was added for testing purpose of more than one code with maximum value.

`XMATCH` can be used for the same purpose too, but it is a more verbose formula:

```
=LET(rng, A2:C13, codes, INDEX(rng,,1), values, INDEX(rng,,2),
 drinks, INDEX(rng,,3),drinksUx, UNIQUE(drinks), 
  maxValues, BYROW(drinksUx, LAMBDA(ux, TEXTJOIN(",",,
    LET(maxValue, MAX(FILTER(values, drinks = ux)),
      FILTER(codes, ISNUMBER(XMATCH(drinks & values, ux & maxValue))))))),
  HSTACK(drinksUx, maxValues)
)
```